# vNext and new task RunDistributedTests - parallel testing

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-devops-rest-api

In TFS update 2 is available new task "[RunDistributedTests](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests)" it can work with test plans and test suites. In my case I want run test suite on 5 machines at the same time (parallel testing)

My test suite include Coded UI tests. The machine group to consists of 5 tests machine.

After execution I see the next result:
The tests running only one machine that is the first at the list of Machine group. Other machines doesn't have any action.

I checked the log file DTAExecutionHost.exe.log and found this exception on each machine where tests doesn't run:

> /tfs/Projects/_apis/test/Agents/97/Commands/0] (GET)0[test]
>   \DTAExecutionHost,
>   TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : A
>   TestExecutionObjectNotFoundException has occured. \DTAExecutionHost,
>   **TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.SendStopCommandToHandleException**
>   : **An exception occured in queue listener.
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.TestExecutionObjectNotFoundException:
>   TestAgent 97 not found. at**
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__79.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Maybe someone has already met with a similar problem I  will be glad of any help
Thanks!

Comment: Did you deploy and configure the test agent on that machine group first? There are tasks for that, as well.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have a step before run test suite -  task "Visual studio test agent deployment"  and I can say with confidence that all machine from group are set up like Test Agent

Comment: **I got answer from Microsoft**:  "Do you have your tests in 1 dll? If so, the parallelism today only works across dlls. We are working on distributing tests within dlls across machines and that should come shortly." [Tasks RunDistributedTests](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1549)