# TFS 2015 Update 3 TestAgent XXXX not found

Tags: coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015

We currently use TFS 2015 Update 3 to run nightly Releases with (only) CodedUI tests. In one Release definition, I have 4 environments that run these tests. 3 of them run fine, but one has consistently run into this error:

> 2018-09-21T19:04:23.8783809Z DistributedTests: Please use this link to analyze the test run : http://...
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:23.8940074Z DistributedTests: Test run '70794' is in 'InProgress' state.
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:23.8940074Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 102, Passed Tests : 0
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:33.9839005Z DistributedTests: Test run '70794' is in 'Aborted' state.
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:33.9839005Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 102, Passed Tests : 0
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0019357Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0956639Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0956639Z ##[warning]Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION).
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0956639Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0956639Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 70794
>
> 2018-09-21T19:04:44.0956639Z ##[error]The test run was aborted, failing the task.

In the DTAlogs, I find this statement:

> E, 8736, 10, 2018/09/21, 10:37:53.264, FALCONVANDV08\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.SendStopCommandToHandleException : An exception occured in queue listener. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.TestExecutionObjectNotFoundException: TestAgent 8984 not found.

I have a Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task before the Run Functional Tests task (remember, 3 other environments that are the exact same handle this fine). The only difference is the VM this is running on, though all 4 of the VMs were created from the same image, and have the same configuration. On the VM, it looks like the vstf_testagent.exe exists and has a timestamp that's similar to when the environment was deployed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems similar as this one : [vNext and new task RunDistributedTests - parallel testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718563/vnext-and-new-task-rundistributedtests-parallel-testing)

Please check [atinb's comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1549#issuecomment-212108278):

> Do you have your tests in 1 dll? If so, the parallelism today only
>   works across dlls. We are working on distributing tests within dlls
>   across machines and that should come shortly.